# Python: can't print dictionary key and value

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a very simple block of code and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong:

```
import sys

o_dict = {'a': 10, 'b': 0, 'c': 20}
for key, val in o_dict.iteritems():
    if val < 1:
        sys.exit("Key: {}, Val: {}.").format(key, val)
```

I'd expect the output to be:

```
Key: b, Val: 0.
```

but instead it's always:

```
Key: {}, Val: {}.
```

What's happenning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your `format` method on the `exit` method, not on the string. This is what you have:

```
sys.exit("Key: {}, Val: {}.").format(key, val)
#                           ^ wrong
```

this is what you want:

```
sys.exit("Key: {}, Val: {}.".format(key, val))
#                                            ^ right
```

Comment: Well don't I feel like an idiot now. I spent 15 minutes trying to figure out what was wrong with this line X( Thank you!

Comment: @Gabriel it happens,  even in answer it took me a while to understand diffrence, so I added comment.

Answer (score 1):

A typo:

```
sys.exit("Key: {}, Val: {}.".format(key, val))
```